# data binding failed in ng2-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to bind array of object to dropdown using ng2-select.It works fine when I tried using array of string

```
private category: Array<object> = [{ "value": 1, "text": "Table" }, { "value": 2, "text": "Chair" }, { "value": 3, "text": "Light"}]
```

and my html as follow:

```
 <ng-select [items]="category" [allowClear]="true"
                                       placeholder="No country selected">
                            </ng-select>
```

I have also Imported selectModule in my module.ts

Comment: Can you be more specific with your problem. Do you get console error or select dropdown is empty?

Comment: select dropdown is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format of your data is not correct.

Instead of:

```
private category: Array<object> = [
    { "value": 1, "text": "Table" },
    { "value": 2, "text": "Chair" },
    { "value": 3, "text": "Light" }
]
```

Use:

```
private category: Array<object> = [
    { "id": 1, "text": "Table" },
    { "id": 2, "text": "Chair" },
    { "id": 3, "text": "Light" }
]
```

The difference is in `value` which represents key of one item. This i ofcourse defined by ng-select module developer.

Comment: but what if data is coming from web api? Is it compulsory to convert data in {id:" ",text:" " } format

Comment: Yes, you need to do that. Since there is no way you can define what is the key and what is the value in your object, it is just not exposed by developer of ng-select. But this is not uncommon in most dropdown modules.