# how to properly bind loaded data to @ng-select, angular5

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular5, angular-ngselect

Working with angular 5 and [@ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) I found some issues binding to previously selected data(in edit forms an such as)

> Ngselect definition

```
 <ng-select
     [items]="contenedores$ | async"
     bindLabel="numero"
     bindValue="id"
     [(ngModel)]="embarqueContenedor.contenedor"> 
 </ng-select>
```

From the api I serialize the entity this way:

> Received from server (json)(this is from the model)

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "numero": "dsvsd",
    "dimension": 234,
    "tipoContenedor": "324",
    "contenedorEmbarques": [],
    "text": "dsvsd",
    "value": 1,
    "name": "dsvsd",
    "createdAt": "2018-03-26T12:44:48-04:00",
    "updatedAt": "2018-03-26T12:44:48-04:00"
}
```

also I fill the ngselect with the items. I received from the server an array with objects like above(actually are the same entity so they are serialized the same way)

Following [this doc](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/demo/app/examples/bindings.component.ts) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543745/data-binding-failed-in-ng2-select) I tried to use both so I add some extra serialized fields(ummaped) and got the above json (text=name=numero,id=value). The problem is that is not working at all, still getting this error from ng-select.js each time I had a selected choice:

> Binding
>   object({"id":2,"numero":"dfdhdf","dimension":324234,"tipoContenedor":"324324","contenedorEmbarques":[],"text":"dfdhdf","name":"dfdhdf","value":2,"createdAt":"2018-03-26T12:44:48-04:00","updatedAt":"2018-03-26T12:44:48-04:00"})
>   with bindValue is not allowed.

The objects have the same and required attributes but still not work

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

when using ngModel with ng-select you have to pass id of the selected value as the following example:

```
<ng-select [items]="countries"
       bindLabel="nested.name"
       bindValue="nested.countryId"
       placeholder="Select value"
       [(ngModel)]="selectedCountryId">
</ng-select>
```

and for multiple selection pass array of ids.

Answer (score 2):

This line is how they are validating that your backing value is valid:

```
    const validateBinding = (item: any): boolean => {
        if (isObject(item) && this.bindValue) {
            this._console.warn(`Binding object(${JSON.stringify(item)}) with bindValue is not allowed.`);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

That's where your error is coming from.  I would guess that this line:

[(ngModel)]="embarqueContenedor.contenedor"

is messing it up, as the `ngModel` is pointing at an object instead of an `id` per `bindValue`.

Try:

```
[(ngModel)]="embarqueContenedor?.contenedor?.id"
```

Comment: Done but as expected only updates the id property on each select not the reference. so when I submit I'm just changing the id on database and that throws exception. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler example, with an array of objects with this formatting

```
{name: 'en'}
```

ng-select declaration:

```
 <ng-select [items]="sourceLanguages"
                 [(ngModel)]="sourceSelection"
                 bindValue="name"
                 bindLabel="name"
                 [clearable]="false"
                 [searchable]="false"                  

      >
```

To get a default selection when over an array of strings `arr = ['en', 'fr', 'de']`, all i needed to input was `this.sourceSelection = arr[1]`; 
So very much along the lines of the answer above: to get a default selection you need to add a property not a whole object. 
It worked for me but your example is clearly more complex...